# responsive Circularprogressindiactor in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

below code changes the size of the circular progress indicator manually, by wrapping it around the sized box and giving dimensions.
I want to make it responsive so that it can adapt to every screen size.

```
SizedBox(
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                 value: 0.5,
                backgroundColor: Color(0xff19454A),
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Color(0xff0b6f75)),
                strokeWidth: 8,

              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.2,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.2,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                 value: 0.5,
                backgroundColor: Color(0xff19454A),
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Color(0xff0b6f75)),
                strokeWidth: 8,

              ),
            ),
```

Comment: will it adapt for tablet shape? its overflowning on screen rotate too

Comment: the size changes depends on the width of device, larger the width, bigger the size, vice versa